# Creating pointer for specific point in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

A little background on the project before I get to the details.  I'm working with a list of ~50 countries with data for somewhere between 40 and 60 years per country.  I've been able to set up a loop for an individual country which tries out various values of a variable (named DELTA in the code) and logs results.

I first bring in the data and clean it to have no null values and create a vector containing all the 3 letter codes used to represent each country using the following code.

```
Clean <- na.omit(Data)
Clean <- Clean[order(country.isocode),]
Codes <- levels(Clean[,2])
```

I then use a loop and the subset function to create a different data frame for each country.

```
for (i in 1:length(Codes)) {
assign((Codes[i]),droplevels(subset(Clean,country.isocode==Codes[i])))
}
```

Now all 50 of my countries are in their own dataframe named after their 3 letter ISO code.  The following is a the code I run to create the results I want for Angola (AGO).

```
AGO_Results <- matrix(numeric(0), 100,2) 
AGOROW<-nrow(AGO)

for (j in 1:100) {
AGO[1,12]<-AGO[1,9]/DELTA

    for (i in 2:AGOROW) {
    AGO[i,12] <- AGO[i-1,12]*(1-DELTA)+AGO[i,9]
    }

AGO[,13] <- AGO[,12]/AGO[,8]

AGO_Results[j,1] <- DELTA
AGO_Results[j,2] <- sum(AGO[,13] > 1 & AGO[,13] < 3)

DELTA=DELTA+.002

}
```

At the end of this AGO_Results contains the values I want, but I'd rather not do this manually for 50 countries, so I'm trying to create a loop around this for all 50 countries.  I've managed using eval() and assign() to get rather far, but I'm stuck on what I think is the last hurdle.

```
for (k in 1:length(Codes)) {


# Initialize Delta and Create Storage Matrix and Row Count
DELTA <- .01
assign(paste(Codes[k],"_Results", sep=""), matrix(numeric(0), 100,2))
assign(paste(Codes[k],"ROW",sep=""), nrow(eval(as.name(Codes[k]))))
```

This portion is complete and works.  Now we're at my real problem, how to reference the individual point [1,12] to be written in each data frame.  What can I do to create a pointer to let me replace an individual item in a data frame, when I have to paste the name of the data frame in each time?

EDIT: Sample Data Posted below

```
country country.isocode year     POP   rgdpl    ki rgdpl2wok        rgdp investment workers L.P
21  Angola             AGO 1970 5605.63 2366.51 23.27   5904.14 13265745651 3087431388 2246856 0.4 
22  Angola             AGO 1971 5752.96 2445.13 23.25   6127.95 14066747655 3270057880 2295508 0.4
```

Comment: Why do you break this up into 50 separate dataframes? That's probably not necessary. You probably don't need the loops either. Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I've added sample data.  Since each country had a different length of years and with the function I want to apply being recursive I thought it would be difficult to get it to start and stop at the correct places for each country.

Comment: you don't need to have start and stop at correct places or think about correct places at all. use split. `?split`

Comment: When I used the split function initially I was unable to droplevels.

Comment: Ok but are you sure you need droplevels? you can convert the relevant variable(s) to character (using as.character) . And yes you can use droplevels - not directly on the list but you can `lapply` it to the list. something like `xxx <- lapply(split(x, list(x$Country)), droplevels)`

Comment: Okay so it's set up and workable with each country factored as xxx$AGO etc.  Now While I'm able to perform functions across the whole thing using lapply to create my response (just a simple ratio of 2 variables), I'm still unable to create the recursive formula to create the important part of this.

I need to initialized each [1,12] as above and then solve for the remainder of the series and write it in.  lapply seems much more difficult than just using referencing and replacing the object as I was doing.

Comment: Well I think it's worth the initial effort. Do you agree that `lapply(xyz, mean)` is easier to understand than something like `for(COUNTRY in COUNTRIES_LIST) assign(paste("mean", COUNTRY, sep="_"), mean(get(paste(COUNTRY, "data", sep="_"))` :) Both compute means by country

Comment: The main question is how to describe the computations you want to do with each country. Can you say it's a function that you apply to that country's data so that the data come in and a value (or a "table" of values) come out? (And the value depends on nothing but the country's data.) In that case, the `lapply` approach is worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a problem with

```
Clean <- Clean[order(country.isocode),]
```

(It will use a global variable country.isocode, not one in the data frame, if there is one. )

Instead of

```
for (i in 1:length(Codes)) {
assign((Codes[i]),droplevels(subset(Clean,country.isocode==Codes[i])))
}
```

you could do

```
xyz <- split(Clean, list(country.isocode))  # or, probably Clean$country.isocode
```

Now you have split the data frame by countries. You can `lapply` a function (possibly self-made) to the resulting list (`xyz`) and you get the results separately for each country. Try this and then say if you really need a "pointer".

#### edit after comments

```
xyz <- split(Clean, list(Clean$country.isocode)) 
xyz <- lapply(xyz, droplevels)  # whatever that's for
```

Now you can define what you want to do with each country (I rewrote your code without trying to understand what it does but noted only an obvious problem):

```
doit <- function(x){
    # where does the DELTA come from? do you initialize it to zero?
    # anyway, you need to define it here or pass it as argument
    Results <- matrix(numeric(0), 100,2)  # I'd use 0 or NA instead of numeric(0)
    NROWs<-nrow(x)

    for (j in 1:100) {
      x[1,12]<-x[1,9]/DELTA

    for (i in 2:NROWs) {
      x[i,12] <- x[i-1,12]*(1-DELTA)+x[i,9]
    }

   x[,13] <- x[,12]/x[,8]

   Results[j,1] <- DELTA
   Results[j,2] <- sum(x[,13] > 1 & x[,13] < 3)

   DELTA=DELTA+.002
   }
   Results # returns results
   }
```

And now you can apply the newly defined function to your list:

```
lapply(xyz, doit)
```

And that should be it. You probably  need a few modifications and trials-and-errors but that's in my view a more sensible approach than creating lots of variables with `assign`.

Comment: Hi I'm taking two pieces of advice at once, but writing two commetns seems like overkill.  I've tried what both are you are saying but it doesn't seem to work well with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've done some tweaking with the function and it's great.  I was initializing DELTA early on as 0.002 and attaching Clean.  Wasn't familiar with writing custom functions and how it interacted with lapply which I was entirely unfamiliar with.  Thanks so much to you and user3207835